# Trouble upgrading .Net Framework 4.8.1 to .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a C# WinForms project using .Net Framework 4.8.1. I'm trying to upgrade it .Net 7. I'm using the [.Net Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant), but I'm getting this error:

```
Error Package 'upgrade-assistant 0.5.261' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'PROJECT_NAME'.
```

I looked in my NuGet package manager, but I don't see anything called DotnetTool.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with your project, the upgrade assistant did not install properly.  You could try installing it again, or use the [VS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-visual-studio-extension), but it might be wise to use another machine.

Comment: Thanks so much! the VS extension fixed it. I'm not sure what the difference is, but it worked. Feel free to post an answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: @JohnDoe Hi, I posted an answer with reference to Hans Passant. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error Package 'upgrade-assistant 0.5.261' has a package type
> 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'PROJECT_NAME'.

This is usually because the .NET Upgrade Assistant extension is not installed correctly.

You can try reinstalling the .NET Upgrade Assistant extension.

Or you can try right-clicking a project in Solution Explorer and clicking Upgrade to update, which can usually fix this issue.

[image]

For details, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-visual-studio-extension

Reference from Hans Passant.